# What statistical analysis should I use for this proposed study?

Tags: correlation, anova, research-design

The aim of this study is to determine the impacts of monolingualism and bilingualism on the literacy skills of primary aged children with ASD. This experiment is a between subject’s design as it will test two groups of participants under equal conditions. The independent variable is the levels of bilingualism and monolingualism across autistic children. The dependent variable is the lexical skills attained.

Comment: Welcome to this site! How are the dependent and independent variables measured (numeric score, qualitative ordered level) and what is your sample size? A few more details about your experimental setup would help refining answers in this case.